# Modify pointer value in Linux kernel

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, linux-kernel, encryption

Firstly, I've create a simple program in C

```
unsigned char * text ="Test program";
int _size = strlen(text);
unsigned char * str = malloc(sizeof(text));
memcpy(str, text, _size);
printf("Before(%d): %s\n", _size, str);
for(i=0;i < _size; i++) {   
    str[i] -= 13; //rot13   
}
printf("After: (%d): %s\n", strlen(str), str);
```

It runs properly. However, when I move this code to Linux kernel, it seems to fail to work

```
unsigned char * str;
len = min(count, log->size - read->off);

/* Allocate the memory for storing plain text */
str = kmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL);
if(str == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "logger: failed to allocate buffer\n");
    return -ENOMEM; 
}
memcpy(str, log->buf + read->off, len);
/* Start: Add a simple rot13 encryption here */
for(i=0;i < strlen(str); i++)
    str[i] -= 13; //rot13
/* End: Add a simple rot13 encryption here */

if (copy_to_user(buf, str, len))
    return -EFAULT;

if(str != NULL) {
    kfree(str);
}
```

The problem comes from following code

```
for(i=0;i < strlen(str); i++)
    str[i] -= 13; //rot13
```

Because if it's removed, program runs as original case. Did I miss something here?

Comment: When you say, it is not working - what do you mean by that? is it crashing the kernel? or giving some unexpected text or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The problem: `sizeof(text)` returns the size *of the pointer*, and not the length of the string `text` points to. Also remember that all string have an extra character that terminates the string. This all means that you write to, and read from, beyond the memory you allocated, and that is undefined behavior which means anything could happen.

Also, literal strings are actually constant (`const char *`).

And lastly, you might want to read about [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot13), as what you're doing is *not* ROT13 encryption.

Comment: Is it defined behaviour to say "ROT13 encryption"? It's like being a "beef-only vegetarian".

Comment: I guess it still is ROT13 in the sense that the whole byte is rotated 13 places instead of just the letters from the alphabet.

Comment: Any suggestion to do it on letter only ?

Comment: @stela How about something like `new_letter = ((letter - 'a' + 13) % 26) + 'a'`. Adjust for capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't terminated `str` with a `'\0'` so you're most likely just running off the end of the buffer and stomping over memory.

Change:

```
str = kmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL);
```

to:

```
str = kmalloc(len + 1, GFP_KERNEL); // allocate additional char for terminator
```

and change:

```
memcpy(str, log->buf + read->off, len);
```

to:

```
memcpy(str, log->buf + read->off, len);
str[len] = '\0';                    // put terminator at end of string
```

Comment: I tried as your comment but it seems to fail also. The problem comes from above code `str[i] -= 13; //rot13` but I don't figure it out yet.

Comment: Did you make *both* of the changes I recommended above ?

Comment: Oh, yes but anything new :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with strings try using strncpy() instead of memcpy. 'coz that will put a NULL char at the end automatically and you are safe from buffer over runs. But in this case, i'm not very sure what exactly is the problem, unless you give more details about the issue.

And for any kernel programming errors, the key is to add debugs/printks and collect as much as data about what is happening. If thats not helping you debug yourself, that will help others to help you better.

Comment: This is a part of android logcat, I just add simple encryption to kernel log driver (driver/staging/android/logger.c) before copying it back to user space so user can not read it easily

Comment: ok I understand that part. but you again did not say what exactly is the problem you are facing. Is it a crash? or something else. Have you tried adding printks and printing the value of i and str[i] before doing operation on it? This will confirm if you are accessing out of bounds or any such thing.

Comment: If I only do `memcpy(str, log->buf + read->off, len);
` then (copy_to_user(buf, str, len)) where str is used as temporary value, it works fine. But if I try to `str[i] -= 13; //rot13
` then (copy_to_user(buf, str, len)); Android boot-up, execute _adb logcat_ then I got the error which comes from following code(system/core/logcat/logcat.cpp)
`else if (entry->entry.len != ret - sizeof(struct logger_entry)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "read: unexpected length. Expected %d, got %d\n",entry->entry.len, ret - sizeof(struct logger_entry));
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}`

Comment: ok, now I feel the kernel may not be the one bailing out. Because you are doing str[i] -=13, you are overwriting the '\0'. So, may be if the uspace program is expecting a null termed string, it might be getting confused. is there a way to check if your read was successful from logcat? And I would strongly suggest to add printk in kernel

Comment: do it this way if you are confused about it, printk ("some info i%d\n", i); add one after copy_to_user and one jsut before return. And, if you have a terminal emulator App for your android device,open it and execute 'dmesg -c' in it. and see the debugs there.